# STM32 Boot from external flash, bootloader for QUADSPI

Tags: flash, stm32, external, bootloader

i need some help over booting from external flash (NOR FLASH) using QUADSPI, problem is i have got very less internal flash and code is of large size hence need an external flash where i can store my code and boot from there only. When i tried directly booting from external flash i found that quadspi is not initialized yet hence no communication with external flash. so what i am thinking is to make a bootloader in internal flash where i only initialize quadspi and then jump to external flash starting address where my code execution starts. please help me in that.

Comment: Kindly help me in figure this out as really need some support here

Comment: Hi, as i did some search over the same, and i found reference code given by ST for Xip which is execute in place. Which is similar to my requirement. But when i tried that code it executes only once and then i need to re program it to execute again. I made some changes in application code where by default ST made controller reset after 20 times of LED blink in every 200 ms, i changed to from that to toggle LED every sec for lifetime. But it only executes one time and when i reset it, it ain't work again until and unless i re programmed it. any suggestions over that ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to boot from the internal flash. Initalize the QSPI interface and jump to the code in the external flash. There is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

try using bootloader, and jump to external flash.

set your app code base addr to ext flash base address.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Could you show me how to place the part of code on qspi ?