# STM32-External_Flash_Memory

Tags: memory, stm32, stm32f7

I am currently working with the STM32F746G-Disco development board and a 7-inch capacitive touch LCD. The size of the generated hex file exceeds the capacity of the internal flash memory. As a solution, I have added an external flash memory (N25Q128A). Could you please provide guidance on how to flash the firmware and configure the system to boot from the external memory? Thank you!

I attempted to flash the external memory and I am now expecting the output to be displayed, with the system booting from the external flash memory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [STM32 Boot from external flash, bootloader for QUADSPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66757834/stm32-boot-from-external-flash-bootloader-for-quadspi)

Comment: It always boots from the internal flash. You just need a small boot app to set up the external flash and load the rest from there.

Comment: Thank you for your response, How can I flash the code onto the external memory?

Comment: If you're not doing it through JTAG, then it will have to be done from the STM32.  Check your dev kit to see if they have a boot loader that supports burning external flash.

Comment: Thank you for your response
When flashing, I encountered the following errors:

Error 1: Failed to erase memory.
Error 2: Unable to get core ID.  
Internal memory erasing was successful but while erasing the external found this error.
Could you please provide guidance on how to overcome the error.

Comment: The next steps are to check to make sure that you have configured the pins correctly.  You're sure you know which STM pins the EEPROM is attached to?  Does that match your bootloader?